# How to fix JDK mistake?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, java

I have downloaded new Android Studio 2.1 and upgraded my `openJDK` to version 8.

[image]

But I have this issue :

[image]

What have I done wrong and what should I do?

Thanks!

added `gradl`

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile files('libs/svgandroid.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'

compile files('libs/guava-16.0.1.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
    'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
    'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
    'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {

buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        dirs.each { dir ->
            java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
            res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
        }
    }
    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
}
}
```

Comment: where is your build.gradle ?

Comment: Are you *running* the IDE with JDK 1.8?

Comment: @DaveNewton i am running `AndroidStudio 2.1` with `openJDK 8` but without succes... Do you have any assume?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

It involves setting a `$STUDIO_JDK` environment variable.

Comment: i haven't tryed it before( but i read out your suggest and try put this list of comands `export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin` then `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` then `export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` and last one `export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre`, but eventually nothing has changed... (( What am i doing wrong?